# Can you reccomend a comprehensive book about Mac OS X internals?

Tags: windows, mac

I'm interested in becoming more familiar with OS X internals. On Windows, I've read both the 4th and 5th editions of [Windows Internals by Mark Russinovich and Dave Solomon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735625301) and they have been invaluable for understanding the way Windows works on a low-level.

Has anyone found a comparable book regarding OS X internals? I'm approaching this as a software developer and security analyst, so a book that incorporates code examples is welcome.

To be clear, I want to understand concepts similar to those presented in the Windows Internals books:

- Understand how the core system and management mechanisms work
- Explore internal system data structures using tools like a kernel debugger
- Grasp the scheduler's priority and CPU placement algorithms
- Go inside the OS X security model to see how it authorizes access to data
- Understand how OS X manages physical and virtual memory
- etc

Does anyone have any suggestions for books on OS X internals covering these types of topics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924035951/http://osxbook.com/book/toc/toc.html) sounds pretty good.

(Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Mac-OS-Internals-Systems-Approach/dp/0321278542/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321278542) )

Comment: What is the magic "googling" you speak of? ;-)

Comment: @Dave M: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=macos+x+internals

Comment: I second that. It's I think the only such (publicly available) book that I know of. I have it and it's quite thorough, though, but does not cover the changes in Leopard and Snow Leopard. A new edition is really needed!

Comment: This book, to be released in Jan 2012, sounds like the one I really want: http://www.amazon.com/Mac-OS-iOS-Internals-Apples/dp/1118057651